# How do I make it appear as if there's an outline around the object, as if it's selected, but this being for appearance reasons

Tags: modeling, layers

[image]
Very much like this orange outline here, but I need this outer layer but purple and part of the actual model itself.

Comment: Apologies, it removed the image.
Edit: Fixed!!

Answer (score 1):

If you need it part of the model, you can use the famous "solidify outline" technique ([tutorial](https://youtu.be/rDVylkVlpr4)).

It works with Cycles too, as long as you use the following logic for the outline material :

[image: Material node tree for the outline material]

Comment: How does that work? Can you share your sources?

Comment: Do you mean the "solidify outline" technique, or the light path trick pictured above ? Both work hand in hand, the former generates an inverted shell around the geometry and the latter allows the underlying mesh to render as if there was no shell around it.

Comment: Primarily the “solidify outline”. It’s better if answers are self-contained or at least point to specific sources.

Comment: I see, apologies I'm pretty new to stackexchange. I added a link to a video tutorial to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle "Freestyle mode" at the Render Properties.
[image]